# Why am I getting an error with regards to char arrays inside of a linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Just trying to wrap my head around linked lists. I'm getting an error "incompatile types when assigning to type char[50]" also "string constant is too long" And finally invalid type argument '->' in the last struct. What do I need to fix?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
struct trainset {
    char name[50];
    int price;
    struct trainset *next;
};

void show_list(struct trainset *list);

int main (void){

    struct trainset *root;
    root = (struct trainset *)malloc(sizeof(struct trainset));      
    strncpy(root ->name, " ", 50);
    root ->price = 0;
    root ->next = 0;

    struct trainset *first_train;
    first_train = (struct trainset *) malloc(sizeof(struct trainset)); 
    root ->next = first_train;
    strncpy(first_train->name, "Fantasy Train Set", 50);
    first_train->price = 129;
    first_train->next = NULL;

    struct trainset *second_train;
    second_train = (struct trainset *)malloc(sizeof(struct trainset));
    first_train->next = second_train;
    strncpy(first_train->name, "Uncle Bobs train set", 50);
    second_train ->price = 69;
    second_train ->next = NULL;

    struct trainset *third_train;
    third_train = (struct trainset *)malloc(sizeof(struct trainset));
    second_train->next = third_train;
    strncpy(third_train ->name, "Budha Bread Train", 50);
    third_train ->price = 169;
    third_train ->next = NULL;

    show_list(first_train);
    return 0;
}

void show_list(struct trainset *list)
{
    while(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("train set name: %s, Train price: %d\n", list->name, list->price);
        list = list->next;
    }
    printf("train set name: %s, train price: %d", list->name, list->price);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of issues here...

1) Your price variable `int price;` is of type "int". Meaning a numeric whole value (no decimal point). Yet when you assign to it you do this:

```
first_train->price = 129.99; // <-- wrong, the .99 isn't going to work there
```

And this:

```
second_train ->price = '69.99'; // <-- wrong... just.. wrong.
```

You'll need to use a double or float if you want these to be number values with a fractional part, or you'll have to use a string if you're not doing math on them

2) The second problem is you're trying to use single quotes for strings. `'` is used for a single character, like `'a'`, double quotes `"` are used for strings, such as `"an apple"`

So if you want prices to be a string you need "69.99", and your names should be the same "Uncle Bobs train set"

3) This is not how you assign a string:

```
third_train ->name = 'Budha Bread Train';
```

You need to use `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` or a function to copy the data into the string.

4) Your list is not "linked". You need to point "next" to the next item in your list, right now you just have four independent structures. If you think of a structure in memory like a "block", something like this:

[image]

So you could generate this with the code you have. You have three independent structures, you can access them by `first_train->price` for example. But they are just that. Three unlinked structures. The "linked" part comes in with those next pointers. You need to "point" each next pointer to the next node, like this:

```
root->next = first_train;
first_train->next = second_train;
```

by doing that you're "connecting" the structures, you can think of it like this:

[image]

If they were linked like this, if I had just one node (the root) I could access anyone's data:

```
root->next->price; //that's first_train's price
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer again Mike. I guess I'm not really seeing the big picture with regards to linked lists. What bits of my code need to change to become linked? Also, I edited the code to adjust of for all the problems. I'm getting a incompatible declaration of strcpy and strncpy.

Comment: @the5thace - You're welcome again. ;) and once again see if my edit helped, I used pictures this time! Let me know if that explains the "linked" part of the list.

Comment: @the5thace - `I'm getting a incompatible declaration of strcpy and strncpy` - that's because you need to `#include <string.h>` to use those string functions.

Comment: Awesome thanks mike. What purpose does the root node serve though? Also, Some of the values are getting mixed up.  Train two is replaces train one and the name of the first train does not appear at all.

Comment: @the5thace you have a copy and paste error, that's why the error with the names. The root node is pretty pointless, normally just a root pointer is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just *assign* to an array, you will have to copy their elements. Also, c-strings are specified with double quotes `"`.

You will need something like this instead:

```
strcpy( first_train->name, "Fantasy Train Set" );
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals are enclosed with the `"` character in C and not with the `'` character. You cannot assign a string but you can copy a string. Use `strcpy` or `strncpy` from `string.h` to copy a string.